# Grab Random Record and Mark As Being Used

Tags: sql, ms-access, random, vba

Alright, so I have a table called Colors, within that table I have 5 records (Red, Blue, Green, Yellow and Orange). The color table currently has two fields (ID and Color Name). My overall goal is to randomly select a color and mark this color as being used. Rinse and repeat until all colors are used and them mark all colors as being unused.

Here is the SQL on the RandomColorsQuery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Colors.[Color Name]
FROM Colors
ORDER BY Rnd(ColorID);
```

So far, I've been able to select a random color by using the following within VBA and works fine:

```
Dim RanColor As DAO.Recordset
Set RanColor = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("RandomColorsQuery")
'MsgBox (RanColor.Fields(0))

Text1.SetFocus
Text1.Text = RanColor.Fields(0)
```

Obviously I would need to add a new field to the Colors table, say a field called "Used". I'd rather not use a Yes/No field and just add an "X" in the "Used" field when the color is used.

Any suggestions or similar examples on how to accomplish this?

Comment: To me it sounds like you are missing some context -- what are the colors being used for?  I would expect a link table that was something like Colors_Map and as you use a color for coloring in the map, you add it to the colors_map table (color_id, map_id) and then you can retrieve which colors you've not used by selecting colors that are not in (select color_id from color_map where map_id=?) for the given coloring project.

Comment: @PlexQ has made good points - but it all boils down to how you're actually using this data. If you're using colors for particular tasks, it requires another table with a 1:M relationship. If you just have an inkling to do exactly what you say, you need another field. Use an update query to mark your new field with an 'X' for the ColorID that was selected.

Comment: since Randoms are not truly a random but a math formula in computer, getting a random ID would not work for you because you might have several chances that you get the same result or already used result again and again. in your case, before getting unused result you need to KNOW which results are used rather than getting random ID and check if its used or not.

Comment: @krishKM typically one populates a List with all unused elements, and then pick a random number from 1 to the length of the list, and use that index, so the primary driver is creating a query that shows a list of unused elements.

Comment: @OverMind if this is truly a one-time use scenario, then simply delete the element from the database once used.  Only unused elements will remain!

Comment: @PlexQ but then what's the point? I am highly doubting the OP wants his tables records to be deleted

Comment: Alright, I don't know how well this is but I ended up creating a copy of the orig table, added a used column and created an update query to mark each color when used by an X. Once all colors are used, another update query created which will null out the used column. Thoughts?

Comment: @Muhnamana we don't know your requirement/structure. I wouldn't advise your method if you are having multiple users, multiple sessions. maybe update the question "Why and what" you are trying to achieve out of this. maybe we might give you a better advise on this

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean (Yes/No) field.

Modify query to return only those that haven't been used:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Colors.[Color Name]
FROM Colors
WHERE USED=False
ORDER BY Rnd(ColorID);
```

In VBA, if the recordset returns a record, grab your color value, and set Used field to True.

If recordset returns doesn't return a record, ie rs.EOF=True, then update Used field in all records to false, and rerun the query to start over.